# How to query keys of objects using Elastic Search?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, typescript, nested

Hi my data is structured in the following manner:

```
student{
 subjects{
   biology:{
     0: "A2-Level"
     1:"AS-Level"
     2:"University"
  }
 }
}
```

My main index is at student, therefore my properties are as follows

```
"mappings":{"student":{"properties":{"subjects":{"type":"nested","properties":{"biology":{"type":"string"},"english":{"type":"string"}}}
```

Im currently doing this search :

```
    var query = {
          index: 'firebase',
          type: 'student',
          "body": {
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [ 
       {
        "nested": {
          "path": "subjects",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                { "exists": { "field": english } }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }

    ]
```

to return the students that are studying english. However nothing is being returned? Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: You need to check for the existence of the `subjects.english` field, not only `english`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check for **subjects.english** field instead of **english**
So, your query should look something like this:

```
{
"query": {
  "bool": {
     "must": [
        {
           "nested": {
              "path": "subjects",
              "query": {
                 "bool": {
                    "must": [
                       {
                          "exists": {
                             "field": "subjects.english"
                          }
                       }
                    ]
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     ]
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore for some reason? Any ideas why? I've checked elastic search documentation

Comment: No idea.. If you can provide more details as to what exception you are seeing or mapping of field that you are searching on... document that you expect in search response

Comment: Never mind it still works !! Was scratching my head for a while but realized I had a trailing space in my query :)